# InternalsVisibleTo seems ignored

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, private, internal

I'm trying to unit test a private function in .net. This private function returns a collection of type `myClass`, which is an internal class.

I've used the assembly attribute `InternalsVisibleTo`, so that the type `myClass` is known to my Test project.

Here's the code I want to test:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Class1
    {
         private List<myClass> myFunction()
         {
             return new List<myClass>();
         }

         internal class myClass
         {
             public int MyProperty { get; set; }
         }   
     }
 }

[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("MyProject.dll")]
public void myFunctionTest()
{
    Class1_Accessor target = new Class1_Accessor(); 
    List<Class1_Accessor.myClass> expected = null; 
    List<Class1_Accessor.myClass> actual;
    actual = target.myFunction();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}
```

and in my assembly info file:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Test")]
```

So why does Visual Studio set the type of the list to `Class1_Accessor.myClass` since `myClass` is known to my test project ?

Because of that I get a runtime error (cannot convert type `myClass` to type `Class1_Accessor.myClass`).

Because myFunction is private, VisualStudio generates the following code (which is fine for most of it)

```
[Shadowing("MyProject.Class1")]
public class Class1_Accessor : BaseShadow
{
    protected static PrivateType m_privateType;

    [Shadowing(".ctor@0")]
    public Class1_Accessor();
    public Class1_Accessor(PrivateObject value);

    public static PrivateType ShadowedType { get; }

    public static Class1_Accessor AttachShadow(object value);
    [Shadowing("myFunction@0")]
    public List<Class1_Accessor.myClass> myFunction();

    [Shadowing("MyProject.Class1+myClass")]
    public class myClass : BaseShadow
    {
        protected static PrivateType m_privateType;

        [Shadowing(".ctor@0")]
        public myClass();
        public myClass(PrivateObject value);

        [Shadowing("MyProperty")]
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public static PrivateType ShadowedType { get; }

        public static Class1_Accessor.myClass AttachShadow(object value);
    }
}
```

However, I don't understand why it contains a new definition of myClass, since it is an internal class, which shouldn't need any accessor. This is the root of the problem in my opinion.

Comment: You might want to add the `mstest` tag to attract the attention of those who are experienced with using Accessors.  I wasn't sure which tag to delete, so I didn't edit the tags myself.  I never much cared for accessors, so I have little experience.  (Further, there's a strong sentiment that you shouldn't be testing private members; if you have a private member that's not indirectly testable through a public one, then it's a sign that you should extract a separate class for that logic.)

Comment: thanks, I've added the tag. Testing private members or not is a whole different topic (although you are right). Nevertheless, I still want to test that one function.

Comment: Regarding the testing of private members, the fact that it's a whole different topic is the reason I put that in parentheses.  And of course there are always defensible exceptions to guidelines like that.  I'd add that when I *have* tested private members I've generally just used reflection -- I even have some helper methods for the purpose (e.g., `CallNonPublicMethod(string methodName)`).  I find that easier to deal with than the accessors -- I never figured out how to get them regenerated when I modified the classes they were shadowing.

Answer (score 4):

> cannot convert type myClass to type Class1_Accessor.myClass

says everything we need to know: simply - you have two different definitions of `myClass`. Types are scoped by assembly; the `[InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` makes it *accessible*, but beyond that: business as usual.

Find why/where you have a second `myClass`, and one of:

- disambiguate (namespace-qualify etc)
- rename one of them
- remove one of them if they mean the same thing, and are incorrectly duplicated

This is exactly the same as having:

```
namespace A { class Foo {} }
namespace B { class Foo {} }
```

that is two completely unrelated classes called `Foo`, and casting between them will fail.

Answer (score 0):

InternalsVisibleTo does not make private members visible to friend assemblies. It works on members/types marked as internal. Check the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

**Update**

Try this (as per this [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182524%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)): regenerate your test class, in the Create Unit Test dialog box, click Settings. In the Test Generation Settings  make sure that Honor InternalsVisibleTo Attribute check box is checked

Comment: Please read my question again.  the type myClass IS Internal, NOT private. It's only the method I want to test that is private.

Comment: yes, myFunction is private so it's normal that VisualStudio creates an accessor for it. However, myClass is Internal (and marked as a Friend in the assembly file) so I don't understand why VisualStudio creates an accessor for it.

Comment: How do you expect to test the private member without the accessor? You probably selected the private method when VS asked for which methods you would want to test.

Comment: That's bad. =( Why can't you have myClass outside Class1?